# City pollution data for data mining project

Tags: data-mining, dataset, bigdata

I want to do my MSc Project on Data Mining. And I want to work on pollution in cities.
Are there accessible and useable pollution data (any type of pollution. e.g. air, water or forest pollution) in specific city or area?
If not, do you have any advice on how to get or search for them?
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The second module of this free machine learning class revolves around working with geospatial pollution data for a river in the Netherlands:

https://www.edx.org/course/applied-machine-learning-microsoft-dat203-3x-1